# Adhoc SQL Server Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex sql requirement where in I need to insert data to target table(set of select statements from a source table) based on values in control table.

The control table has got list of products with attribute1, attribute2 and action columns(INCLUDE/EXCLUDE)

This insert is based on  value of action column which is done at product level(For each product).

For action INCLUDE we have two cases:

1.when attribute2 is not null, For every product insert that attribute1/attribute2 combination alone and exclude all other atrribute1 combination(for that product)

2. when attribute2 is null, For that product include all attribute1 combinations

For action EXCLUDE in control table we have two cases:

1.For every product exclude the mentioned attribute1/attribute2 combination and include all other atrribute1 combination (for that product)

2. when attribute2 is null, For that product exclude the mentioned attribute1 combinations and include all other attribute 1 combinations

Below is the source table /control table and the values in it.

```
create table #source(
Product varchar(100),
attribute12Value varchar(100),--(its a combination of attribute1,attribute2, some value)
colx varchar(100),
coly varchar(100),
)

create table #control(
attribute1 varchar(100),
attribute2 varchar(100),
value varchar(100),
Product varchar(100),
action varchar(100)
)

insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'HP', 'hw1-i3proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'HP', 'hw2-i3proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'HP', 'hw2-i5proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'HP', 'hw2-i7proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'HP', 'hw3-i3proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'Dell', 'hw1-i3proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'Dell', 'hw1-i5proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
insert #source(Product ,attribute12Value ,colx,coly)
select 'Dell', 'hw1-i7proc-ver1-sale','normal','Y'
```

Based on the action value in the control table the output from source table should be as below:

--case1 when attribute2 not null
--For every product insert that attribute1/attribute2 combination alone and exclude all other atrribute1 combination(for that product)

```
insert #control(attribute1 ,attribute2,value ,Product,action)
select 'hw2','i3proc','ver1','HP','INCLUDE'
```

--For every product exclude the mentioned attribute1/attribute2 combination and include all other atrribute1 combination (for that product)

```
insert #control(attribute1 ,attribute2,value ,Product,action)
select 'hw2','i5proc','ver1','HP','EXCLUDE'
```

--case2 when attribute2 is null
-- For that product include all attribute1 combinations

```
insert #control(attribute1 ,attribute2,value ,Product,action)
select 'hw2',NULL,'ver1','HP','INCLUDE'
```

-- For that product exclude the mentioned attribute1 combinations and include all other attribute 1 combinations

```
insert #control(attribute1 ,attribute2,value ,Product,action)
select 'hw3',NULL,'ver1','HP','EXCLUDE'
```

Similarly this logic applies to all other products such as DELL which is then inserted into the target table.

I am able to find a INCLUDE logic like this:

```
select T1.Product,T1.attribute12Value,T1.colx,T1.coly from #control T
 inner join #source T1 on T.action='INCLUDE' 
 and T.Product=T1.Product and PATINDEX(T.attribute1+'-'+isnull(T.attribute2,'')+'%',T1.attribute12Value)!=0
```

But I am stuck at the EXCLUDE logic where I need to exclude the mentioned attribute1/2 combination and include all other attribute1 combinations.

[Sample Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rZX7.png)

Can a general TSQL logic be applied for such a requirement to EXCLUDE records based on a control table?

Thanks.

Comment: Formatting please...

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL (for SQL-Server version 2008+) has an [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) set based operator.

Given query A, to exclude a set of rows defined by query B from the result set :

```
-- result set
SELECT * FROM A

EXCEPT

-- rows to exclude/remove from result set
SELECT * FROM B
```

so for your exclude case 1 (for each product include all rows having specified attribute1, then remove all rows having specified attribute1/attribute2 combination) :

```
select T1.Product,T1.attribute12Value,T1.colx,T1.coly from #control T 
inner join #source T1 on T.action='EXCLUDE' and T.Product=T1.Product AND [... Your predicate for selecting all attribute1 combinations ... ] AND attribute2 is not null

EXCEPT

select T1.Product,T1.attribute12Value,T1.colx,T1.coly from #control T 
inner join #source T1 on T.action='EXCLUDE' and T.Product=T1.Product AND [... Your predicate for selecting the combination attribute1/attribute2 ... ] AND attribute2 is not null
```